# How to keep only numbers in text from bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies

I want all my cite references to have numbers in them from 1 to N but make references section empty (no source information, pages names volumes...). How to do such thing in latex?

Comment: Let me make sure I understand what you're looking to achieve: (a) create numeric style citation call-outs in the body of text (numbered sequentially, so probably using a bib style such as `unsrt`, right?), and (b) furnish a completely empty bibliography -- no (authors'?) names, etc. Please advise if this understanding is correct. If it is, and assuming the bibliography would occur (if it weren't invisible...) at the end of the document, have you considered (a) inserting a `\clearpage` directive immediately before `\bibliography{whatever}` and (b) deleting the final few pages from the pdf file?

Comment: Or you could just say `\chapter*{\bibname}` or `\section*{\bibname}` at the end in place of `\bibliography{whatever}`, I think. That is, after getting all your citations finalised, remove the `\bibliography` and just create the heading at the end of the document, @Mico ? But what are the numbers for exactly? I mean, what is a reader supposed to want them for if they don't point to anything?

Comment: @Mico: Ended up with a simple new page before real references and removed that page after compilation.;) thank you!)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as since the OP's issue was solved by some of the comments.